# How can I set maximum number of chips for mat-chip input?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to let a user input only one chip in mat-chip with auto complete.
I know md-chips has md-max-chips to set maximum number of chips.
but I am using mat-chip and how can I set maximum number of chips like this?

```
<mat-chip-list maxLength="1">
  :
  :
</mat-chip-list>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't set it directly on the `MatChipList` as far as I know. What you could do is, check the number of selected chips yourself for each chip the user is trying to add and then decide whether to add the chip or not, based on the number of chips already added.

> Check out
>   [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-hpdh1t?file=app/app.module.ts)
>   stackblitz taken from the official documentation and modified to solve your problem.

All I changed was this (when adding chips via auto-complete):

```
selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
  if (this.fruits.length < 1) { // <-- THIS
    this.fruits.push(event.option.viewValue);
    this.fruitInput.nativeElement.value = '';
    this.fruitCtrl.setValue(null);
  } 
}
```

And this (when adding chips via typing):

```
add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
  // Add fruit only when MatAutocomplete is not open
  // To make sure this does not conflict with OptionSelected Event
  if (!this.matAutocomplete.isOpen) {
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;

    // Add our fruit
    if ((value || '').trim() && this.fruits.length < 1) { // <-- THIS
      this.fruits.push(value.trim());
    }

    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }

    this.fruitCtrl.setValue(null);
  }
}
```

Basically you check the number of chips already selected, before you add any new chips. Edit your code accordingly, the above examples should cover both cases (auto-complete and typing).

Answer (score 0):

i have some validation chip count with 250 characters

while add i did.. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-gigxiw?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
  const len = this.fruits.join('');

  // Add our fruit
  if ((value || '').trim() && len.length <= 250) {
    this.fruits.push(value.trim());
  }
```